# Visual Studio 2012 "Extensions and Updates" "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, connection, nuget, nugetgallery

This has been the case unfortunatly for the past couple of months. I can't install new or update packages from **Tools ==> Extensions and Updates** I tried everything, yet I am unable to find the reason. 
I've tried :

1. Access NuGet and download packages from "**Package Manager Console**" *Install-Package* = **SUCCESS**
2. Access repositories using Web browsers, Visual studion internal browser = **SUCCESS**
3. Same window in Visual Studio 2010 = SUCCESS

#### Visual Studio 2012 - **Doesn't work**

[image: Visual Studio 2012 - Online packages]
[image: Visual Studio 2012 - Update packages]
[image: Visual Studio 2012 - update gallery packages]
[image: Visual Studio 2012 - Installed packages]

#### Visual Studio 2010 - **Works!**

[image: **Visual Studio 2010** - Online packages]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Can you try to manually navigate to the following and see if it works? `http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/`

Comment: JaredPar - Yes I can navigate to that in a regular browser, and inside of the VS browser.

Comment: Carlos487 - Yes, I am behind one. It I have AutoDetect in my browser, and what interesting is that VS2010 can connect, see the screenshots above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out for some reason -possibly due to an RC-, My registry settings were pointing to a different url that was getting redirected.

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\ExtensionManager\Repositories**

AND I changed

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\ExtensionManager\Repositories{0f45e408-7995-4375-9485-86b8db553dc9}(Default)

to
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Services/v2011/Extension.svc
**instead of**
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=251029

I changed

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\ExtensionManager\Repositories{aeb9cb40-d8e6-4615-b52c-27e307f8506c}(Default)

to 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Services/v2011/sample.svc
**instead of**
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=251031

Comment: I don't know about the accepted answer, but this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the local cache of extensions and download them all again.

The easiest thing to do is to rename

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Visual Studio version\Extensions\

to

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Visual Studio version\Extensions.old\

and run visual studio, it will update recreate the folder.

Answer (score 5):

*WeSam Abdallah*'s hint worked perfectly for me! Just try to open the link provided in *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\ExtensionManager\Repositories{0f45e408-7995-4375-9485-86b8db553dc9}(Default)* in your browser and see what it is changed to automatically. For Visual Studio **2013** I had to change the URL from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309922 to https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/services/dev12/extension.svc

Comment: Man, this is the best thing after enjoying Noam Chomsky's videos :) Saved the day, the month and the year! The new address my browser redirected me to didn't work - the one from your reply did the trick. Kudos there (bow)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an update for Visual Studio 2015.

I tried the registry hack as well as renaming the Extensions folder, and neither solution worked.

However, in my case, the issue seems to have been because I'm behind a proxy at work. This worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32650801/2452084