# Visual Studio 2015 - Visual Studio Gallery Error while connecting to Visual Studio gallery for extensions and updates

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-gallery

When trying to get a visual studio extension from Extensions & Updates, I get the following error:-

An error occurred while making the HTTP request to visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Services/VStudio/Extension.svc

I can see that few others have faced [this problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fdca2fe-204c-43c4-a438-ad06f9936acd/visual-studio-2015-rtm-visual-studio-gallery-error-and-unable-to-sign-in?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fdca2fe-204c-43c4-a438-ad06f9936acd/visual-studio-2015-rtm-visual-studio-gallery-error-and-unable-to-sign-in?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fdca2fe-204c-43c4-a438-ad06f9936acd/visual-studio-2015-rtm-visual-studio-gallery-error-and-unable-to-sign-in?forum=vsx), but I can't see any solution anywhere. Also, a similar error occurs when trying to fetch nuget package.

PS: The message is a bit misleading as with svcutil, I can create a proxy using the same address:-
svcutil https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Services/VStudio/Extension.svc

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when you are behind a proxy.

Try to close Visual Studio and update the `devenv.exe.config` file located in

 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`
and search for the `system.net` node.
If it isn't there then add it, otherwise change it to look like this:

```xml
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="true" bypassonlocal="true" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This will cause Visual Studio to use the system defined proxy and use your credentials if the proxy requires you to logon.

Comment: I can confirm this works in VS2015 Pro; the only new part to add is the <defaultProxy> section. I don't have to do this at home, but at work this was necessary. Thanks! This was driving me nuts.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I still get a timeout and I have no idea why.

Comment: Got the same problem on different networks.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ff56d2d-04c1-4df5-8776-df4fe806082e/unable-to-load-list-of-online-extentions-an-updates?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: I tried this solution and it broke the homepage (with news and videos). So without that node, my homepage work but I get timeouts on the gallery inside the Tools > Extensions menu

Comment: This setting will only work when you're behind some kind of firewall and need a proxy server to connect to the internet.