# Visual Studio 2012 "Visual Studio Gallery" A Connection could not be established", "there was no endpoint listening"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am trying to update/install nuget but when i open visual studio gallery under extensions and updates i get "A connection to the server could not be established because of the following error(s) occurred:

There was no endpoint listening at http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/services/VS2012/Extension.svc that could accept the message...

Remote server returned an error: (404) not found.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfdGk.png)

I have tried solution from link:"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131422/visual-studio-2012-extensions-and-updates-unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-ser"  but they did not work for me.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go to ***TOOLS > Extensions and Updates > Updates*** and update your VS.

I had the same problem and this solution fixed it.